# Connect to Azure HDInsight Kafka cluster from public network / local machine

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight

Is there a way to connect to Azure HDInsight Kafka cluster from the public network without using a VPN ?
Is it only possible to connect to Azure Kafka cluster from with in Azure network ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a VPN. Just open the firewall ports from Azure

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have you tried connecting to Azure from public network ? Can you exactly tell me how to do it ?  Is it also possible to connect to aws msk kafks service from outside world ?

Comment: Doesn't matter where resources are located. You just pay more money for egress traffic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: It is mentioned here that we have to use a VPN to connect to Kafka Cluster: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/connect-on-premises-network

The link you mentioned is for exposing a VM to an outside network, not the Azure HDInsight Kafka Cluster to the public network

Comment: HDInsight is just a collection of VM resources